# What type of variant is "protection" when compared to "protect"?

Tags: variants

You have variations of [**Protect**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/protect) such as

- third-person singular simple present **protects**
- present participle **protecting**
- simple past and past participle **protected**

So what would you call **protection**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first three words cited (*protects, protecting, protected*) are [***Inflected forms***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) of the verb *protect*. Note that they are all the same verb, with the same meaning, just different ones for different purposes. Inflection is a large part of [***Morphology***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29), but not the only part -- and in English, not a big part at all. There are only 8 or 9 different possible inflections left in English, and this is three or four of them.

The other part of Morphology is ***Derivation***, as in *protection, protective, protectiveness, unprotected*. Derivation frequently changes the part of speech of a root, so as FF points out, this is a noun, not a verb. It's also irregular, variously productive, and non-paradigmatic, as the ungrammatical forms **protecthood,* **protectation,* and **protectify* show. But there's a lot of it in English.

These and other differences between derivation and inflection are detailed on the [first page here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf).

Comment: Surely there are contexts where, for example, *protecting* (as a [gerund noun](http://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/noungerund.htm)) and *protection* are exact synonyms. It's not obvious to me how useful it is to distinguish between the two forms by saying one is an *inflection* and the other is a *derivation*. Is the distinction more relevant in some other contexts?

Comment: As it says in the [link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf), "an affix or other chunk of grammar is usually either derivational or inflectional, though there is a certain grey area between them." _**-Iŋ**_ is a good example. There turn out to be several different kinds of _-ɪŋ_ morphemes, which can be distinguished from one another syntactically. One is a simple noun, another the progressive marker, and still another is [the true, the blushful gerund](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gerund.html), etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Protection* is the **noun** form derived from the verb. Other common [noun suffixes](http://www.lovetolearnplace.com/Grammar/grammarsuffixes.html) are, for example, *-sion, -ment, -ness*